# Generating angular/typescript class that specifies allowed values for property

Tags: angular, typescript

Imagine I'm making a simple model that describes (for instance) the details of a query:

```
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: string;
}
```

That `sortDirection` is much more vague than necessary.  After all, the API accepts either `asc` or `desc`, and no other string values are allowed.  Therefore it would be nice to specify that only those two values are allowed, but I'm not quite sure how I would specify such a property, and the typescript docs haven't helped.  In essence I want to do this:

```
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: 'asc' | 'desc';
}
```

Except of course the union operator works with types, not values.  I could conceptually try something like this:

```
export class asc {
   direction = 'asc';
}
export class desc {
   direction = 'desc';
}
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: asc | desc;
}
```

But even if that works the structure of my model has changed (the sort direction is now `model.sortDirection.direction` instead of `model.sortDirection`)

Is there an obvious option that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried your hunch ? Because it does work like that. Those are `Type`s, and they accept values, just like you suspected.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

Comment: I just plugged it into a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qhvxvx) and it appears to be working fine with the union operator.

Comment: @Maryannah lol, that's embarrassing.  I'm still putting together the skeleton of the app, so neither the tests nor the app are running yet for me to "test" it out.  I browsed through the doc that Reactgular linked to (I have a number of times actually), but missed that section and didn't know the name of the thing I was looking for to google it.  I just assumed it didn't work since I didn't see anything about it in the docs.  Obviously I should have just waited a bit longer as I would have answered my own question once I got the tests running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there are a variety of ways how to go about your requirement.

First and foremost, the simplest way is to do it like you actually suggestted

```
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: 'asc' | 'desc';
}
```

Second is to declare a type, and use it instead. This might be beneficial for reusability

```
export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc';

export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: SortDirection;
}
```

The third option is to define an Enum. In addition to reusability, using an enum makes the code more maintainable; example in the case that the value `asc` and `desc` need to change in the future, you only need to change the value of the enum (instead of all going through all the places, as is the case with type definitions).

```
export enum SortDirection {
    ASC = 'asc',
    DESC = 'desc'
}

export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: SortDirection;
}
```

Comment: I forgot about enums!  I don't use those much, so handy to have the reminder.  Thanks for breaking out all the options!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a type

```
Type sortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc';
```

And use it in your class

```
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: sortDirection = 'asc';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a "literal type" with union values.

`export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc';`

and use it in your model:

```
export class QueryModel {
    filters: FilterModel[];
    page: number;
    pageLength: number;
    sortField: string;
    sortDirection: SortDirection;
}
```